# UPDATE SQL, only UPDATE image if not null

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to allow users to update a table that has an image file-upload input. Only the filename is stored in the database, such as image.jpg. My problem is that if the user chooses not to change the image it clears what is in the database since it sends a null value. How do I only update the IMAGE field if input file is not null?

```
        // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE News SET 
                                        TITLE=?, 
                                        CONTENT=?, 
                                        IMAGE=?
                                        WHERE ID=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssd", $title, $content, $image, $id);
```

Comment: Use a conditional statement then; that's what they're there for ;-) `if(condition){ do something } else{ do something else }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- So, if image is not null, $stmt = $conn->prepare(...) else $stmt = $conn->prepare(...) ?

Comment: Pretty much Steve. `if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){ execute SQL }`

Comment: *....then all the answers started rolling in like oranges* - Quiz: Now, who said that? Ah yes... Maxwell Smart ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Duh, for some reason I never thought of using a conditional statement with the SQL statement. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome Steve. You can now take your pick of the many answers given below lol was glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: Unless you want me to post one to close 'er up; that's up to you ;-)

Comment: Post an answer to close 'er up Fred, you had the correct answer first :)

Comment: The deed has been done Steve; was glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It couldn't be any simpler than using a conditional statement:

The logic:

`if(condition){ do something } else{ do something else }`

Which you could use in conjunction with your `$_FILES` array and as an example:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){ 
  // execute SQL 
}

else{
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, as you might want something more complicated

```
if (isset($image) && !empty($image))
{
    // your code
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE News SET 
                                    TITLE=?, 
                                    CONTENT=?, 
                                    IMAGE=?
                                    WHERE ID=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssd", $title, $content, $image, $id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work for all cases, adding to Don Djoe's answer:

```
if (isset($image) && !empty($image))
{
    // your code
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE News SET 
                                TITLE=?, 
                                CONTENT=?, 
                                IMAGE=?
                                WHERE ID=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssd", $title, $content, $image, $id);
}
else
{
    // your code
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE News SET 
                                TITLE=?, 
                                CONTENT=?
                                WHERE ID=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssd", $title, $content, $id);
}
```